# Cannot proceed wizard of adding custom domain on Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase

I am trying to add custom domain to my new app on Firebase Hosting. Following official documents, I pressed "add custom domain" button in my project's Hosting page and stared a wizard.

In the wizard step 1, I entered my domain "example.com" and press "next" button without check a redirect checkbox. Then spinner stared to spin but after 1-2 seconds, spinner disappeared and the wizard were still on step 1.

I deleted the app and deployed again but same problem was occurred. Also I tried in secret window of Chrome but the situation did not change.

The domain is connected to old VPS server.

Any error was not shown.

How can I solve this?

I tried to another domain as a test but the result is same. Deleting and recreating the project did not affect the problem.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy4Ue.png)

Answer (score 0):

I changed login user from google workspace to normal gmail. Then everything work fine.